# How would I do a if else statement and display inner html but with a url in the innerhtml

Tags: javascript

Ignore the first form box. My goal here is to let the user click their favorite station using the `radio-button` from the second form. Once they click the favorite station and click the button it should `pop up` and give them the url using `innerhtml` to their favorite station.

Only one favorite station should be selected. I only did the real url for the first one as you can see the rest I left as `alert` boxes to test out but will change later. I am getting errors and don't know how to approach the `if-else` statements. Please Help thank you.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Lab 8</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function radio() {
 var theMix = document.getElementById('mix');
var theDrive= document.getElementById('drive');
var theCountry= document.getElementById('country');
            if (document.getElementById("mix").checked) 
                {
                      document.getElementById("mix").innerHTML = "https://wtmx.com/";

                }

     else if (document.getElementById("drive").checked) {

         alert("www.yolo.com");
     }
else if (document.getElementById("country").checked) {

    alert("www.helloworld.com")
}

        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <p>List all the stations you listen to <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="A">The mix 101.9 <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="B">The Drive 97.1 <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="C">US 99 Country 99.5 <br>
        </p>

    </form>



    <form>
        <p>What is your favorite station?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="stations" id="mix" value="A">
        <label for="mix">The Mix 101.9</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="stations" id="drive" value="B">
        <label for="drive">The Drive 97.1</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="stations" id="country" value="C">
        <label for="country">US 99 Country 99.5 </label><br>
        <input type="button" value="Link To Favorite Station" onclick="radio()">
    </form>


</body>





</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mix` is input element `InnerHTML` not supported.And also its a radio button .You need to change text value of label not input. so do with `attr` selection using `querySelector`

```
document.querySelector("label[for=mix]").innerHTML = "https://wtmx.com/";
```

```js
function radio() {
  var theMix = document.getElementById('mix');
  var theDrive = document.getElementById('drive');
  var theCountry = document.getElementById('country');
  if (document.getElementById("mix").checked) {
    document.querySelector("label[for=mix]").innerHTML = "https://wtmx.com/";

  } else if (document.getElementById("drive").checked) {
document.querySelector("label[for=drive]").innerHTML = "https://wtmx.com/";
  } else if (document.getElementById("country").checked) {
document.querySelector("label[for=country]").innerHTML = "https://wtmx.com/";
  }

}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>List all the stations you listen to <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="A">The mix 101.9 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="B">The Drive 97.1 <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="C">US 99 Country 99.5 <br>
  </p>

</form>



<form>
  <p>What is your favorite station?</p>
  <input type="radio" name="stations" id="mix" value="A">
  <label for="mix">The Mix 101.9</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="stations" id="drive" value="B">
  <label for="drive">The Drive 97.1</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="stations" id="country" value="C">
  <label for="country">US 99 Country 99.5 </label><br>
  <input type="button" value="Link To Favorite Station" onclick="radio()">
</form>
```

Comment: how would I make the  .innerHTML show up on an element below the input
form?

Comment: you mean this text value `<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="A">The mix 101.9 <br>` `The mix 101.9`

Comment: you know how when i click option one the url pops up. I want that url to pop up below the form because right the inner html makes the url pop up on the option itself